# Smtp Server Timeout error

Tags: email, smtpclient

I am trying to send mail using SmtpClient and below is my code.

```
 SmtpClient client_ = new SmtpClient("relay-hosting.secureserver.net", 25);
            //client_.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            //client_.EnableSsl = true;
           // client_.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            //client_.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(_fromAddress, _password);

            MailAddress from_ = new MailAddress(_fromAddress, _fromName);
            MailMessage msg_ = new MailMessage(from_, from_);

            msg_.Subject = "Subject";

            StringBuilder body_ = new StringBuilder();
            body_.AppendLine("Line1");
            body_.AppendLine("===============================================================================================");
            body_.AppendLine("Line2");
            body_.AppendLine("===============================================================================================");
            body_.AppendLine("line2");
            body_.AppendLine("===============================================================================================");

            msg_.Body = body_.ToString();
            msg_.IsBodyHtml = true;
            client_.Send(msg_);
```

I am getting TimeOut error.  When Same smtp configuration using in email client on my machine, it send the mail immediately.  I don't know what can be cause.  Also when I used my Gmail account with gmail smpt server it worked.

Comment: What server and port?  This is a network or server issue.

Comment: I talked about the issue with hosting provider.  They given me different smtp server for relaying.

Comment: I am getting error System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientException: Mailbox name not allowed. The server response was: sorry, relaying denied from your location.  I have updated the code. but still getting error.

Comment: I asked technical support team at godaddy.com and they said, it will work on hosting web server.  It will not work on my local machine.  Is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most consumer ISPs block port 25 to prevent you from running a mail server.
Therefore, you cannot connect to port 25 from your house.

You can ask them for an alternate port.
Try port 587; it's commonly used as well.

Comment: I did configuration change and using smtp.gmail.com from local machine and relay-hosting.secureserver.net on prod server, and this is working for me.  However, I'll try your suggestion when time permits.  Thanks